# How to build a javascript countdown timer that doesn't reset on page refresh?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found this code from this site: https://www.sitepoint.com/build-javascript-countdown-timer-no-dependencies. This code gives a countdown timer that resets on page refresh.

```
function getTimeRemaining(endtime) {
  var t = Date.parse(endtime) - Date.parse(new Date());
  var seconds = Math.floor((t / 1000) % 60);
  var minutes = Math.floor((t / 1000 / 60) % 60);
  var hours = Math.floor((t / (1000 * 60 * 60)) % 24);
  var days = Math.floor(t / (1000 * 60 * 60 * 24));
  return {
   'total': t,
   'days': days,
   'hours': hours,
   'minutes': minutes,
   'seconds': seconds
 };
}

 function initializeClock(id, endtime) {
 var clock = document.getElementById(id);
 var daysSpan = clock.querySelector('.days');
 var hoursSpan = clock.querySelector('.hours');
 var minutesSpan = clock.querySelector('.minutes');
 var secondsSpan = clock.querySelector('.seconds');

function updateClock() {
var t = getTimeRemaining(endtime);

  daysSpan.innerHTML = t.days;
  hoursSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.hours).slice(-2);
  minutesSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.minutes).slice(-2);
  secondsSpan.innerHTML = ('0' + t.seconds).slice(-2);

  if (t.total <= 0) {
    clearInterval(timeinterval);
  }
}

 updateClock();
var timeinterval = setInterval(updateClock, 1000);
}

  var deadline = new Date(Date.parse(new Date()) + 15 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
  initializeClock('clockdiv', deadline);
```

Later on the article the author says to implement the below code to the above code to get a timer that won't reset on page refresh. Since I'm a beginner, I could not implement the code properly. so can you please help me to do it properly. Thanks.

Here's the code and the instruction author gave:

Maintain Clock Progress across Pages

Sometimes it’s necessary to preserve the state of the clock for more than just the current page. For example, if we wanted a ten minute countdown across the site, we wouldn’t want the clock to reset every time the user goes to a different page or every time the user refreshes the page they are on.

One solution is to save the clock’s end time in a cookie. That way, navigating to a new page won’t reset the end time to ten minutes from now.

Here’s the logic:

If a deadline was recorded in a cookie, use that deadline.
If the cookie isn’t present, set a new deadline and store it in a cookie.

To implement this, replace the deadline variable with the following:

```
 // if there's a cookie with the name myClock, use that value as the deadline
 if(document.cookie && document.cookie.match('myClock')){
 // get deadline value from cookie
 var deadline = document.cookie.match(/(^|;)myClock=([^;]+)/)[2];
}

  // otherwise, set a deadline 10 minutes from now and 
  // save it in a cookie with that name
 else{
  // create deadline 10 minutes from now
  var timeInMinutes = 10;
  var currentTime = Date.parse(new Date());
  var deadline = new Date(currentTime + timeInMinutes*60*1000);

  // store deadline in cookie for future reference
  document.cookie = 'myClock=' + deadline + '; path=/; 
  domain=.yourdomain.com';
 }
```

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @Pointy, I couldn't implement the code properly. so i need someone who can do it the right way.

Comment: @AKM looks like you just copy/paste the cookie code block in place of the `var deadline` line in the first code block, and put your domain on the domain line. What part are you having problem with? Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Comment: @AKM: You should tell where you're stucked with this. Because I just can thank you for this article which I bookmarked for future use. There is no start point in your question to help you out. Did you checked for console errors? What is not working? Explain!

Comment: @MichaelCoker, no errors in the browser console.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette Bro, I just want a working counter timer that doesn't reset on page refresh. I need the full JS code. can u give me the code pls?

Comment: @AKM: I asked you to edit your question by telling what *exactly* is not working. This is the starting point for all SO questions : To be able to define this. Hit the "edit" link below your question and improve it. If possible, create a [CodePen](http://codepen.io/) with the full code or provide a live link.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette bro, forget everything. just give me the code of a counter timer that doesn't reset on page refresh please please please.

Comment: @AKM: Welcome to StackOverflow! This is a question/answer forum, not a code request market place. I do not "have" such a code you're asking. But if you post code snippet you've a tried and know approximately where you're stucked, based on the syntax, SO users like me can help.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP asks for a working code without making any more efforts than a copy/paste.

Answer (score 1):

Here is code (although I don't recommend learning programming by just copy/pasting):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Timer</title>
        <script>
        var timeoutHandle;
        function countdown(minutes,stat) {
            var seconds = 60;
            var mins = minutes;

        if(getCookie("minutes")&&getCookie("seconds")&&stat)
        {
            var seconds = getCookie("seconds");
            var mins = getCookie("minutes");
        }

        function tick() {

            var counter = document.getElementById("timer");
            setCookie("minutes",mins,10)
            setCookie("seconds",seconds,10)
            var current_minutes = mins-1
            seconds--;
            counter.innerHTML = 
            current_minutes.toString() + ":" + (seconds < 10 ? "0" : "") + String(seconds);
            //save the time in cookie

            if( seconds > 0 ) {
                timeoutHandle=setTimeout(tick, 1000);
            } else {

                if(mins > 1){  
                setTimeout(function () { countdown(parseInt(mins)-1,false); }, 1000);

                }
            }
        }
        tick();
    }
    function setCookie(cname,cvalue,exdays) {
        var d = new Date();
        d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays*24*60*60*1000));
        var expires = "expires=" + d.toGMTString();
        document.cookie = cname+"="+cvalue+"; "+expires;
    }
    function getCookie(cname) {
        var name = cname + "=";
        var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
        for(var i=0; i<ca.length; i++) {
            var c = ca[i];
            while (c.charAt(0)==' ') c = c.substring(1);
            if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
                return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
            }
        }
        return "";
    }
    window.onload = function startingTimer(){
        //countdown(prompt("Enter how many minutes you want to count down:"),true);
          countdown(2,true);
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="timer">00:00:00</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Note: This code is not mine, I took it from [here](http://navaneeth.me/simple-countdown-timer-using-javascript/#.WLJ9_jvyuUk) and edited it a little bit for your needs.

Comment: Thanks so much. Pls do me another favor. what to do if I don't want the prompt input?

Comment: @AKM It depends on how you want to set up timer. If you wanna fix time (always same time) you can just delete this part: "prompt("Enter how many minutes you want to count down:")" and replace it with number in minutes, example for that line would be  countdown(2,true); for 2 minutes.
And yes, I would be grateful if you could mark my answer as right one, thank you.

Comment: Slay, It's not working. 1st one also not working. what can i do now?

Comment: @AKM I edited my answer. Try it now. It's set up for 2 minutes